# Restarting with stat error when debugging flask app with PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, flask, debugging, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a small flask app and I had a few errors I wanted to try and fix with the PyCharm debugger, but when I try to run the debugger the following pops up:

*Restarting with stat

C:\Users\nare2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Here's the relevant (last) lines of my code:

```
>     if __name__ == "__main__":
>         with app.app_context():
>             db.create_all()
>             app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error too, and can not solve this problem, and I think the problem caused by the Pycharm, It's a software bug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at the [PyCharm support forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11602067518226-C-Program-Files-Python311-python-exe-can-t-open-file-C-Program-Errno-2-No-such-file-or-directory) to make sure that you don't install PyCharm in a location with spaces (which is quite difficult on Windows machines).

A quick work-around is to make a Junction to the installation directory of PyCharm by using a path that does not contain any spaces, using the command line, e.g.:

```
mklink /J C:\software\PyCharm "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.2"
```

And then start PyCharm from the \bin folder in the newly created junction. Alternatively update the symlink from the Windows Start menu to point to this new location.